# Vertical align image within parent div with css

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

So I'm trying to vertical align images within a container div. I tried adding vertical-align: middle; to the parent div with no luck.

```
    <div class="contributor_thumbnail"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="contributor_thumbnail"><img src="image.jpg"></div>

.contributor_thumbnail {

    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is set the image as a background image.

```
.contributor_thumbnail {
    /* Background image instead of using and img tag */
    background: url(image.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="contributor_thumbnail">
<div class="content">
    <img src="image.jpg"> 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contributor_thumbnail  {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}
.content    {clear:both; height:240px; position:relative;}
```

Inspired by: [Lost in the Woods vertically centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

Comment: Thanks! I used `line-height: 2em;` since I only had a number to center.

Answer (score 0):

```
.contributor_thumbnail img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Comment: This is for horizontal centering, not vertical