# Vertically aligning images in a fixed height div

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I have searched the knowledge base high and low, but nothing seems to give me a result.

I have attached a screenshot and code of the content I'm working on below, but what I'm needing to do is vertically align the images based on the height of the div created by the tallest image.

So, a few things. The fixed height of the container .one-edition is determined by the tallest image size - can I do this with JS?

Then, once the height is determined, the images are aligned vertically in the middle.

Hope this makes sense.

```
    <div class="grid_3 one-edition">
<a href="product-1.php"><img src="images/editions/1_Right_To_Buy_295.jpg"></a>
        <div class="editions-info-text">
            <p>Right To Buy</p>
            <p>C-type Print</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 one-edition">
        <a href="product-1.php"><img src="images/editions/2_Scorer_295.jpg"></a>
        <div class="editions-info-text">
            <p>Hyperbolic Paraboloid Roof</p>
            <p>Offset Print</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 one-edition">
        <a href="product-1.php"><img src="images/editions/3_PL16_295.jpg"></a>
        <div class="editions-info-text">
            <p>132Kv PL16</p>
            <p>Offset Print</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 one-edition">
        <a href="product-1.php"><img src="images/editions/4_What_We_buy_295.jpg"></a>
        <div class="editions-info-text">
            <p>What We Buy</p>
            <p>Publication</p>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: CSS is hell for vertical aligning. There's various hacks to implement it, but they all have caveats, restrictions, and requirements. If only there was a universal solution, like... say... `vertical-align: middle`.. but noOoOoOoo... the W3C doesn't think anyone ever needs to align vertically.

Comment: `vertical-align:middle` should work on elements with `display:table-cell` so the CSS treats it as a table and it's still semantically not a table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical align image within parent div with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583962/vertical-align-image-within-parent-div-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see many answers already but I'm still posting this, because I spent time using placekittens..

http://jsfiddle.net/7ybzp/6/

Basically, I used `vertical-align: middle`. I used `inline-block` though.

Comment: Haha - thanks for this. Works great but my one-editions are float:left which breaks this answer.

Comment: I managed to fix this by changing `inline-block` to `table-cell` when the divs are floated.